# Update review on Google Play after refund

Tags: google-play-store

Yesterday I've downloaded a paid app from Google Play store but it didn't work as I expected so I gave it a 1 star rate and I asked for a refund.

Then i've read again the app description and I realized I did wrong assumption about how it gotta work.

Now I would like to remove or at least update the review I did because it was my bad and the app got no trouble at all.

Apparently I cannot do it and the bad review will stay there forever.

Any idea about how to fix this?

Do you think Google should give the chance to update reviews despite refund?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found this page that seems to address your issue. Maybe try to delete the review whilst on your computer if you've been trying on your phone or vice versa. It does say ''Note: You can only review apps you have previously downloaded and installed. When you download an app, it's linked to your Google Account. '' I'm wondering if the link between your account and the app is only deleted if the app was a paid app. Because I have previously downloaded free apps then deleted them from my device and the link between my account and the app is still present.

Hope this helped

[link to google support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)